# Mixins / mixing modules and files

Tags: module, rust, visibility, file-structure

I know that you can have multiple modules in a single file using the `mod` keyword. I know that you can also split a module across several files using the file structure described in the tutorial:

```
├── english
│   ├── farewells.rs
│   ├── greetings.rs
│   └── mod.rs
```

I am looking for a mix of these functionalities. Specifically, I have a set of modules in separate files:

```
.
├── main.rs
├── constant.rs // module
├── function.rs // module
├── matrix.rs   // module
└── ops.rs      // module, but probably shouldn't be
```

These are separate modules, but I would prefer to only have `constant.rs`, `function.rs`, and `matrix.rs` be modules and to have `ops.rs` simply augment these three modules. The objective is to allow `ops.rs` to access private methods in those three modules. Right now I have to make those methods public, which is undesirable.

I'm looking for something similar to Ruby mixins or C++ 'friend' functions.